# Erro no Spring data JPA (Parameter 0 of constructor e entityManagerFactory)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data, spring-jpa

Galera, faz horas que eu estou tentando resolver um problema no meu Spring data JPA
Executo o cógido e recebo esse erro

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in br.com.aluguel.de.carros.alugador.AlugadorServiceImpl required a bean named ''entityManagerFactory'' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named ''entityManagerFactory'' in your configuration.
```

Como se o construtor do meu AlugadorServiceImpl estivesse 0, mas não está!!
Já procurei em todo lugar na internet, fala pra adicionar umas dependencias no meu pom.xml, eu adiciono e o erro persiste

O meu AlugadorServiceImpl esta assim:

```
package br.com.aluguel.de.carros.alugador;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class AlugadorServiceImpl implements AlugadorService {
    private AlugadorRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public AlugadorServiceImpl(AlugadorRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Alugador> todos() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Alugador> alugador(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Alugador novo(Alugador alugador) {
        alugador.setNome(alugador.getNome());
        return repository.save(alugador);
    }

    @Override
    public Alugador atualiza(Alugador alugador) {
        Alugador alugadorAtualizado = repository.save(alugador);
        //repository.reflesh(alugadorAtualizado);
        return alugadorAtualizado;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deleta(Long id) {
        Optional<Alugador> alugadorOpt = alugador(id);
        if (alugadorOpt.isPresent()) {
            repository.delete(alugadorOpt.get());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Meu pom.xlm esta assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.tmf</groupId>
    <artifactId>gp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>gp</name>
    <description>WebApp Para gerenciar projetos</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Meu AlugadorService esta assim:

```
package br.com.aluguel.de.carros.alugador;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface AlugadorService {
    List<Alugador> todos();

    Optional<Alugador> alugador(Long id);

    Alugador novo(Alugador alugador);

    Alugador atualiza(Alugador alugador);

    boolean deleta(Long id);
}
```

E meu AlugadorRepository esta assim:

```
package br.com.aluguel.de.carros.alugador;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AlugadorRepository extends JpaRepository<Alugador, Long> {
}
```

Alguem me ajude por favor, já não sei mais o que fazer

Answer (score 2):

Precisava adicionar a relação na Entidade

```
@OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_endereco")
    private Endereco endereco;
```